# Relation between different ML models

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, mathematical-statistics

Is there a paper or book that talks about the mathematical relation between different machine learning models - how they are different and how they can (sometimes) be equivalent?

For instance logistic regression can be viewed as a single-layer perceptron. Other examples are [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Boltzmann_machine#Relationships_to_other_models)

Answer (score 2):

[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://books.google.nl/books?id=kTNoQgAACAAJ&dq=pattern+recognition+and+machine+learning&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tnIPUYu_M4uR0QWIx4GoBg&redir_esc=y) by Christopher M. Bishop does this a bit. It's a tough read, but usually worth it once you make it through.

For instance:

- He discusses Gaussian Processes in the context of Kernel methods (like Support Vector Machines) and briefly discusses their connection to Neural Networks.
- He starts his discussion of the EM algorithm with an explanation of k-means clustering.
- He describes Bayesian Networks and Markov Random Fields under the heading of Graphical Models.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While it does do some of that, it's scattered all over the book. It would be really nice to have a document that does this in one place and tries to relate as many models as possible...

Comment: A agree that that would be a nice resource. I don't know of any, but it'd be a worthwhile thing to set up (maybe in wiki format, so it can be kept up to date).